How can I debug this error occuring when trying to install pyzmq?
I try to install this specific package in Python: pip install pyzmq==25.0.2
This gives a following error:
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
      20 errors generated.
      ************************************************
      ************************************************
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang++' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

Note:This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyzmq Failed to build pyzmq
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyzmq,
                       which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Is there a specific version of Python I need to use? I tried Python 3.8 and 3.12. I also tried the steps that an automated-chat-application gave me - with same error.
Background: I am using a Mac, and with great difficulty I figured out how to install pip - the command pip install pyzmq==25.0.2 is used in a package build (cognite) that I am trying to run using poetry: poetry add cognite.

Did you ever get a fix for this? I'm running into the same issue

Can you post your actual Mac hardware architecture? Best as lscpu output + lstopo-no-graphics -.ascii

Your error doesn't seems to be a python version issue.
However, try to upgrade your pip version with :
pip install --upgrade pip

if that doesn't help, try this in a virtual environment.
Finally, if nothing works try to install an earlier version of pyzmq

I tried these and tried to install the previous versions of pyzmq. I get the same error for versions 19 and up. For version 18.0.0, I get the following error:
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [1 lines of output]
error in pyzmq setup command: 'python_requires' must be a string containing valid version specifiers; Invalid specifier: '!=3.0*'
[end of output]

Did you ever get a fix for this? I'm running into the same issue?
